# bevy 0.12 keeps creating bevy-render 0.11.3<

Tags: rust, serde, bevy, rust-wasm, wgpu-rs

I wanted to modify and build this app to wasm: https://github.com/janhohenheim/foxtrot/tree/v0.3.0

After some refactors I have removed particles plugin, added my own features and now want to build it to wasm with trunk.
It runs fine on native, but It has many problems on wasm, which I slowly eliminate.

The compile command is:

`RUSTFLAGS=--cfg=web_sys_unstable_apis trunk build --release`

I almost found the answer [here](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/issues/10583), but there is a problem with cargo.lock file(probably with serde).

It keeps compiling bevy-render-0.11.3

```
[[package]]
name = "bevy_render"
version = "0.11.3"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "39df4824b760928c27afc7b00fb649c7a63c9d76661ab014ff5c86537ee906cb"
dependencies = [
 "anyhow",
 "async-channel 1.9.0",
 "bevy_app 0.11.3",
 "bevy_asset 0.11.3",
 "bevy_core 0.11.3",
 "bevy_derive 0.11.3",
 "bevy_ecs 0.11.3",
 "bevy_encase_derive 0.11.3",
 "bevy_hierarchy 0.11.3",
 "bevy_log 0.11.3",
 "bevy_math 0.11.3",
 "bevy_mikktspace 0.11.3",
 "bevy_reflect 0.11.3",
 "bevy_render_macros 0.11.3",
 "bevy_tasks 0.11.3",
 "bevy_time 0.11.3",
 "bevy_transform 0.11.3",
 "bevy_utils 0.11.3",
 "bevy_window 0.11.3",
 "bitflags 2.4.2",
 "bytemuck",
 "codespan-reporting",
 "downcast-rs",
 "encase",
 "futures-lite 1.13.0",
 "hexasphere",
 "image",
 "js-sys",
 "naga 0.12.3",
 "naga_oil 0.8.2",
 "parking_lot",
 "regex",
 "serde",
 "smallvec",
 "thiserror",
 "thread_local",
 "wasm-bindgen",
 "web-sys",
 "wgpu 0.16.3",
 "wgpu-hal 0.16.2",
]
```

After cargo update I have issues with serde:

[image: Serde errors]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Check what package depends on `bevy 0.11.3` (for example with `cargo tree`)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, thanks cafce25, the warbler_grass v0.4.0 module uses bevy 0.11.3. That's werd because the whole project seems to use Bevy 0.12. I will check if removing or upgrading the warbler_grass package will solve the problem.

Ok, there is still a problem with bevy-rapier-3d and maybe oxidized-navigation, however the versions seems to be correct with Bevy.

[image: rapier-3d]

[image: warbler_grass]